# Strong interaction under $SO(3)$ isospin transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, variational-principle, classical-field-theory

I'm given the following strong interaction: $$S = \int d^{4}x [\frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \phi^{a} \partial^{\mu} \phi^{a} - \frac{m^2}{2} \phi^{a} \phi^{a}] ,\qquad a = 1,2,3 \text{.}$$ It is stated that $S$ is invariant under an $\text{SO}(3)$ transformation (arbitrary rotation it seems like) $\phi^{a} \rightarrow \Lambda^{a} \text{ } _b \phi^{b}$. But how is it invariant? Is the procedure to verify this done by replacing $\phi^{a}$ with $\Lambda^{a} \text{ } _b \phi^{b}$ in $S$ and checking that the variation $\delta S= 0$? Also, what effect if any will this have in computing the currents related to the isospin transformation? Is the current conserved, and would it be an electric charge?

Comment: I may have to consider the stress energy tensor, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever indices are repeated up and down and assumed to be summed over, they are always invariant under rotations because they are nothing but the scalar product between a vector and its dual (or more precisely, the action of a dual vector onto a vector). Such scalar product is invariant under orthogonal transformations, hence the eventual result will be, too.

Equivalently: raising (respectively lowering) indices is obtained by application of the metric tensor, which is left invariant by rotations (by definition of rotations).
In fact given $v^{\mu}$ then $v_{\nu} = g_{\nu\mu}v^{\mu}$ and therefore $v^{\mu}v_{\mu} = g_{\nu\mu}v^{\nu}v^{\mu}$; the lower indices of the tensor will then transform with twice the transformation matrix and each of the upper indices with the inverse (or viceversa). Overall result is invariant.

I believe your Lagrangian must be assumed to be $\partial_{\mu}\phi^{\alpha}\partial^{\mu}\phi_{\alpha}$, that is, the $\alpha$ indeces are up and down summed over. If so, the above automatically applies since $\Lambda$ only acts on the $\phi$ degrees of freedom (internal rotation, as you have mentioned), leaving the derivatives with respect to the coordinates $\mu$ untouched. Left to prove is that the measure in the integral is invariant under rotations too, but usually measure are always taken to be so.